# Ligar ao clicar em um button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que ao clicar em um button, já fosse realizada uma chamada telefonica para o número.

Como eu fiz, ele chama a activity Action_Diall com o número já escrito, então a pessoa deve clicar novamente para realizar a chamada.

É possível que ao clicar neste botão (do app) já realize a chamada?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
else if (id == R.id.btn_call){
            String celular = saveSharedPreferences.getNumber(getContext());
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+celular));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer chamada telefônica no Android diretamente, você deve usar `ACTION_CALL`. Veja como ficaria:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+celular));
startActivity(call);
```

Além disso, é necessário dar permissão no seu *manifest* `android.permission.CALL_PHONE`.

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).